# ASCII-EBCDIC Java converter, using COMTBLG Microsoft SNA Server GTable

Tags: java, character-encoding

I'm actually working on a Java Host integration. The actual system uses Microsoft SNA Server, where an ASCII-EBCDIC conversion is done based on local COMTBLG Gtable. Do you know the specification of this file? Is there anyone having coded a Java program to read it?

Thanks in advance.

Esteve

Answer (score 1):

The IBM toolset [JTOpen](http://jt400.sourceforge.net/) has the conversion routines you need in it.

Comment: Really useful API. Do you know which class does allow me loading/working with COMTBLG file? Thanks again for your quick help ;)